# Como transformar mais de um vetor em matriz utilizando a linguagem php?

Tags: php, array, matriz

Eu tenho um arquivo `matriz_caminhos.txt` com 20 linhas e 20 colunas, preciso acessá-lo e pegar os dados como uma matriz.

Até o momento, eu apenas consegui que ele varresse o arquivo e me retornasse 20 vetores.

Segue o código:
.

```
<?php

            $ponteiro1 = fopen("C:/xampp/htdocs/www/grafoai/inputs/matriz_caminhos.txt","r");

              while (!feof($ponteiro1)) {

                  $linha1 = fgets($ponteiro1, 4096);     
                  //var_dump($linha1);      

                  $caminhos1 = array_map('trim', explode(",", $linha1)); //cidades = vetor

                  $vetorCaminhos = array();                    

                  foreach ($caminhos1 as $key1 => $value1) {

                    //Array
                    $vetorCaminhos = str_split($value1);
                    echo "<br><br>";
                    print_r($vetorCaminhos);                                    

                   } //Fim do Foreach      


            } //Fim do While

            fclose($ponteiro1)          

        ?>
```

O arquivo "matriz_caminhos.txt" contém os seguintes dados:

```
01010000000000000000
10100000000000000000
01010000000000000000
00100100000000000000
00001010000000000000
00000101000000000000
00000010100000000000
00000001010001000000
00010000100001000000
10100000011000000000
00010000000100000000
00000000110100000000
00000000001011100000
00000000000100000000
00000000000100010100
00000000000000101000
00000000000000010000
00000000000000100000
00000000000000000101
00000000000000000010
```

Estou utilizando o mapa a seguir como exemplo. Cada número 1 que está no arquivo txt representa a posição da cidade no mapa e suas ligações (Para poder, eventualmente, saber qual o melhor caminho a ser percorrido).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Eu estava tentando pegar os dados como vetor e depois transformar em
>   matriz. Existe alguma possibilidade de já **pegar esses dados como
>   matriz**? Se sim, qual? Se não, existe alguma possibilidade de
>   **transformar esses 20 vetores em uma matriz**?
>
> Só para exemplificação, quando eu escolhi como origem a cidade "Arad"
>   e cidade destino como "Eforie" e escolhi o método Amplitude. Eu devo
>   utilizar uma lista encadeada para fazer a busca do melhor caminho
>   possível através do método amplitude.
>
> Após eu selecionar cidade de origem, destino e método, eu com o código
>   acima, consegui que imprimisse os 20 vetores, como mostra a imagem
>   abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isso é um problema de Grafos, e não lista encadeada, como está na tag

Comment: Na explicação do professor, pelo que eu entendi, eu deveria usar uma lista encadeada pra guardar os dados para fazer a busca.

Comment: Sim grafos tem duas implementações mais populares, matriz e lista de adjacências. Lista encadeada utiliza ponteiros para ligar estruturas instanciadas. http://www.professeurs.polymtl.ca/michel.gagnon/Disciplinas/Bac/Grafos/RepImpl/rep_impl.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não entendi por que você trata a primeira linha diferente. Aqui vai um exemplo que gera uma matriz 4x4, você pode adaptar para o seu caso:

```
$str = "0010\n1011\n0000\n0101";
$matriz = [];
$linhas = explode("\n", $str);

foreach ($linhas as $linha) {
    $colunas = str_split($linha);
    $matriz[] = $colunas;
}

print_r($matriz);
```

Comment: Ah sim... então, eu estou começando com php... Dai estava fazendo alguns testes pra ver como funciona e tudo mais. Obrigada, vou adaptar aqui.